# Can't load table from json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I want create a table with JSON using Javascript and obtaining data from a database and show it on my page when I load it. This table thas to have a link to put the data in the selected row into textboxes.

To fill the table I use a **method on .asmx**:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public void CargarUsuarios()
    {
        var wcf = new wsDN.ServicioClient();
        var respuesta = wcf.Listar_Usuario().Valor.ToString();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Write("{" + $"\"data\" : {respuesta}" + "}");
    }
```

and this is how I create my **table**:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl_Usuarios">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID Usuario</th>
                                    <th>Cédula</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                                    <th>Usuario</th>
                                    <th>Contraseña</th>
                                    <th>Opciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

and this is the **JS**:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#tbl_Usuarios').DataTable({
                        "language": {
                            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Spanish.json"
                        },
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "/Contenido.asmx/CargarUsuarios",
                            "type": "POST",
                            "dataType": "json"
                        },
                        "columnDefs": [
                            {
                                "targets": 6,
                                "orderable": false,
                                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                    return '<a href="#">Modificar</a>';
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Comment: whta chrome console > network tab say about sending request (do request was send? do response contains data?)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: probably you need some library which will add DataTable property/function to jquery/html element (this jquery plugin https://datatables.net/ ?  )

Comment: agree with Kamil. DataTables is not found. make sure it loads before your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to add some library which will Add `DataTable` property/function to jquery/html element (do you use this jquery plugin datatables.net ? )